# RecylcerView scrolls to Top on Item Removed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use the following Code in my RecyclerView.Adapter to remove an Item. If the current scroll-position is at the top, everything works fine.

If the scroll-position is somewhere in the middle of the List, the List automatically scrolls to the Top of the View.

How to avoid this behaviour?

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

...

    public void removeItem(int pos){
        mDataset.remove(pos); //List with Items
        notifyItemRemoved(pos);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(pos,mDataset.size());
    }
}
```

---

```
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
...
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What are the resons behind `notifyItemRangeChanged(pos,mDataset.size());` ? It seam like you are only removing one item as give pos

Comment: These two lines are more than enough 

 mDataset.remove(pos); //List with Items
 notifyItemRemoved(pos);

Comment: tried using only 'notifyItemRemoved(pos)' already. Same Beviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following Line solved it for me

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: Even though this seems like a ghetto fix, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

for recycler view you use
`yourRecylerView.scrollToPosition(position);`

Just check whether this position is present in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
mDataset.remove(pos);
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to scroll to the position removed after notifying the dataset associated with the `RecyclerView` is changed.

And yes, you just have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after removing an item from the `mDataset`. So your adapter will look like this.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    //... Code goes here 

    public void removeItem(int pos){
        mDataset.remove(pos); 
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(pos - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: better would be to use notifyItemRemoved or notifyItemRangeRemoved instead so that you only need to update the items that actually changed, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. mDataset.remove(pos);
2. adapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);
3. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public void removeItem(int position){

    mdata.remove(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mdata.size());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use recyclerView inside nestedScrollView and had the same issue. Here is the code to call to remove an item

```
    mDataset.remove(pos) // Remove from dataset
    notifyItemRemoved(pos) // Show animation of removing
```

And here are lines to be added to XML to make it scroll correctly (RecyclerView is focused with higher priority than its viewHolders so it won't scroll)

```
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

After that everything was ok.